# Adding a default value to a combobox

Tags: javascript, extjs, combobox, playframework

I have a combobox with 5 values and I want to set one as the default value. How would I do this?

This is the code for my combox and I want to set '14' as my defalut value:

```
{
                            xtype:'combo',
                            store: ['11','14','23','28','29'],
                            triggerAction: 'all',
                            labelStyle: 'width: 125px',
                            fieldLabel: 'Zone',
            id: 'zone',
                            id: 'rtZone',
                            width: 110
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

The docs are your friends.  Use `value`: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Field-cfg-value